# How to change html tag attribute value from RJS template?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

Is it possible to change a html tag attribute value from an RSJ template?
I know that there is a page.replace_html method, but it is not very useful in my case, since I have lengthy values of various attributes (such as alt, title of an image).
What I want is change src attribute of a img tag in RJS.
Is that possible at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** My first attempt didn't work, but this one does.

```
update_page do |page|
  page['image_id']['src'] = new_image_url
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Slight modification to Can's answer.  As suggested,

```
update_page do |page|
    page['image_id']['src'] = new_image_url
end
```

translates to JS:

```
$('image_id').src = new_image_url
```

This will work for some attributes that have direct JS DOM variable access, many don't.  Luckily RJS is pretty good at rewriting JS method calls:

```
update_page do |page|
    page['image_id'].set_attribute('attrib', new_attrib_val)
end
```

translates to JS:

```
$('image_id').setAttribute('attrib', new_attrib_val)
```

and you should be good to go.

---

Small update: you may want to use write_attribute instead if you want IE compatibility.

---

Small update: in the above, [:src] and :attrib would probably be better style if these are static.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Rails setup, the code above might work only if you exclude the page_update start and end lines -- I'm running Rails on mongrel on Windows 7, and putting the page[element][attribute] code on its own, outside of the update_page block, works fine, but including it inside the block breaks the code.